# Zooming rectangle not displayed in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

In ol 3.10, I am trying to use this code to zoom, but it is not displaying my zooming rectangle.

```
ol.interaction.DragZoom.dragZoom= new ol.interaction.DragZoom ({
  condition: ol.events.condition.always,      
});
```

What is the possible reason?

Comment: in openlayer v3.13 its creating issue .. please try lower version ...say v3.9.0. I also faced the same issue . Later i found Openlayer3.13 having issue in Style . Thanks
Pravin

Answer (score 2):

They have resolved the bug, now you just need to use this CSS to style your box:

```
.ol-dragzoom {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add the style stuff when initialising????
check this might help

```
myapp.Navigation.Tools.dragZoomInt = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
    condition  : ol.events.condition.always,
    style      : new ol.style.Style({
        fill       : new ol.style.Fill({
        color      : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke     : new ol.style.Stroke({
            color    : '#319FD3',
            width    : 3
        })
  })
});
```

Comment: thank you @pavlos. I tried your way. But I can't still see zooming rectangle

Comment: when initialising your map, do you use the `renderer` option???? And if yes what do you asign there?

Comment: I had some kind of this problem when using 'webgl'. Thats why I am asking. The piece of code you provide seems correct. Though , this is just the tree out of the forest. Unless you provide the whole code or better a fiddle we can not do much to help you.

Comment: it is usual map init.( or I guess so) var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([ 
      new ol.control.ScaleLine({units:'metric',
            className: 'ol-scale-line', target: document.getElementById('scale-line')}),
            overviewMapControl,
      new ol.control.FullScreen()

    ]),
    
  target: 'map',
  renderer: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([36.0, 39.0],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 6
  })
});
zoom bounding box has vanished.

Comment: Within your code I dont see any interaction. Where do you initialise your interaction?????? check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/8o72zgun/ it is a combination of your code plus I have added the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.ol-dragzoom {
    border: 3px solid red !important;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```